# BlazorStrap Server not working with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

```
services.AddBootstrapCss();
services.AddScoped<ILoggerRepository, LoggerRepository>();
```

My IDE complains that AddBootstrapCss

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddBootstrapCss' and no accessible extension method 'AddBootstrapCss' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Reference
https://blazorstrap.io/V1/

This is a .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6 upgrade so I am not sure what the replacement would be for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, I found that the cause of the problem is that the official documentation has not been updated. AddBootstrapCss is supported when blazorstrap is in version <= `1.5.1`.

[image]

In the latest document, there is no update in the quick use tutorial, but I found a sample whose official link is invalid, [you can refer to this repo](https://github.com/chanan/BlazorPrettyCode/blob/79f7cd11778608f2298c8b3d0902c1bcf6a04a9e/src/ServerSideSample/Startup.cs).